# A simple select query taking 8mins on 30 million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has 30 million rows and it's increasing dayily but now just simple select query like

```
Select top 10 * from table order by entrydate desc
```

Is taking more than 8 mins, any solution for this ?

Comment: The index will help if there isn't one already. But [read this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) on what people need to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: 800 column table?

Comment: ordering non indexed column definitely slow it down, but 8min sounds to much anyway. I noticed sometimes it runs slower if no where clause. You can add where 1 = 1 if there is nothing to filter

Comment: adding a predicate could speed things up (assuming it's on a SARGable column), but why would 1=1 specifically speed it up @MikeTwc ? Are you sure that it isn't a foldable expression that would be ignored and wouldn't show up in the query plan anywhere?

Comment: Adding `WHERE 1 =1` is only going to slow down the query, if anything, as it's an expression the query analyser had to resolve, and it doesn't filter the data at all. It certainly won't make an improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need an index:

```
create index idx_table_entrydate on table(entrydate);
```

Comment: Thanks , how does it make the difference? How indexing works?